# LINQ and nullable parameter

Tags: c#, linq, nullable

I have a nullable field in DB and nullable parameter in model. I try the following LINQ to Entities query:

```
        EditPersonViewModel model = (from i in db.Person
            where i.PersonID == id.Value
            select new EditPersonViewModel()
                {
                    PersonID = i.PersonID,
                    Fullname = i.Fullname,
                    Comment = i.Comment,
                    Username = (i.UserId != null) ? i.AspNetUsers.UserName : String.Empty,
                    // this is parameter has type "int?"
                    PersonStatusID = (i.PersonStatus!=null) ? i.PersonStatus.PersonStatusID : null
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the compilation error:

> Error 1   Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because
>   there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and ''

it works fine with

```
Username = (i.UserId != null) ? i.AspNetUsers.UserName : String.Empty,
```

but does not work with "int?" type. Why and how to do it correctly?

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ. It is a compiler error. 90% of the code here is not required to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Can you not `(int?)PersonStatusID = (i.PersonStatus!=null) ? i.PersonStatus.PersonStatusID : null` ?

Comment: can't. And PersonStatusID already has type "int?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation of [Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) says:-

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Since `i.AspNetUsers.UserName` & `String.Empty` are `string` types its working fine for you. Now, your problem is self explanatory because null cannot be casted to integer type, you need this instead:-

```
PersonStatusID = (i.PersonStatus!=null) ? i.PersonStatus.PersonStatusID : 0;
```

Or the other way around if you need that as Nullable of integer:-

```
PersonStatusID = (i.PersonStatus!=null) ? (int?)i.PersonStatus.PersonStatusID : null;
```

`PersonStatusID` should be of type `int?` in this case.

Comment: Just an addition he can cast it to `nullable` type also.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya - Yeah both ways its possible but it all depends on the datatype of `PersonStatusID`